# geojson very slow to load in openLayers3

Tags: geoserver, geojson, openlayers-2

I'm new to openLayers. I have parcel data stored in a geojson file, and it's pretty huge - there are about 170,000 records. I would load the data as a WMS, but I want the features to highlight in a different color on mouseover. I'm following this example:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/vector-layer.html?q=geojson

I'm assuming I can't apply this functionality with a WMS layer? But the performance is just too slow with the geojson. I've also tried setting maxResolution and minResolution for the vector layer but it doesn't seem to make a difference - it also doesn't seem to work no matter what I set the values to (but I could be doing something wrong - I don't yet know how the resolutions correspond to zoom levels). Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Comment: 170k of features will be too much for the web browser you might need geoserver to pull on request using WFS for GeoJSON http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can publish the data to geoserver, so if I pull the data from geoserver as WFS it will speed things up?

Comment: yes use a bounding box to just pull that data to the user/browser less data = faster rendering see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187937/loading-geojson-layers-from-geoserver-to-leaflet-map-based-on-the-current-boundi

Comment: thanks, I need to find a similar snippet using openLayers